# Pyside - cannot connect signal when using args

Tags: python, pyside

I’m having a reoccurring problem when trying to connect a method to a signal in Pyside

Inside my class :

```
myButton = QPushButton()
someLineEdit = QLineEdit()
myButton.clicked.connect(self._someMethod (someLineEdit))
```

The _someMethod function is a class method

When I include arguments in my method, the error states ‘ Failed to connect signal clicked()’

If I remove arguments from the method, it connects fine. 
I have tested this passing in a simple string instead, but still get the same error

Is there a workaround , or known limitations in using connect in this manner ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the callable function (or slot) as an argument to your `connect()` function for this to work. The way you do it now you call the function `self.someMethod()` and pass the result to `connect()`. Change your code like this:

```
myButton.clicked.connect(self._someMethod)

def self._someMethod():
    # do something here
    print(self.sender())  # this prints the sender of the event
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `partial` for that:

```
from functools import partial

myButton.clicked.connect(partial(self._someMethod, someLineEdit))
```